# How to make secondary DirectBuffer sound?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am trying to get sound from simple tapping keyboard. Looks like a little drum machine.
If DirectSound is not a proper way to do this, please suggest something else.
In my code I don't know what's wrong. Here it is without error checking and with translations:

```
//Declaring the IDirectSound object

IDirectSound* device;

DirectSoundCreate(NULL, &device, NULL);
device->SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, DSSCL_NORMAL );

/* Declaring secondary buffers */
IDirectSoundBuffer* kickbuf;
IDirectSoundBuffer* snarebuf;

/* Declaring .wav files pointers
   And to structures for reading the information int the begining of the .wav file */
FILE* fkick;
FILE* fsnare;
sWaveHeader kickHdr;
sWaveHeader snareHdr;
```

The structure **sWaveHeader** is declared this way:

```
typedef struct sWaveHeader
{
char            RiffSig[4];        // 'RIFF'
unsigned long   WaveformChunkSize; // 8
char            WaveSig[4];        // 'WAVE'
char            FormatSig[4];      // 'fmt '
unsigned long   FormatChunkSize;   // 16
unsigned short  FormatTag;         // WAVE_FORMAT_PCM
unsigned short  Channels;          // Channels
unsigned long   SampleRate;
unsigned long   BytesPerSec;
unsigned short  BlockAlign;
unsigned short  BitsPerSample;
char            DataSig[4];        // 'data'
unsigned long   DataSize;
} sWaveHeader;
```

The .wav file opening

```
#define KICK "D:/muzic/kick.wav"
#define SNARE "D:/muzic/snare.wav"
fkick = fopen(KICK, "rb")
fsnare = fopen(SNARE, "rb")
```

Here I make a function that does the common work for **snarebuf* and **kickbuf**

```
int read_wav_to_WaveHeader (sWaveHeader* , FILE* , IDirectSoundBuffer* ); // The declaring
```

But I wil not write this function, just show the way it works with kickbuf, for instance.

```
fseek(fkick, 0, SEEK_SET); // Zero the position in file
fread(&kickHdr, 1, sizeof(sWaveHeader), fkick); // reading the sWaveHeader structure from file
```

Here goes a checking for fitting if sWaveHeader structure:

```
if(memcmp(pwvHdr.RiffSig, "RIFF", 4) ||
       memcmp(pwvHdr.WaveSig, "WAVE", 4) ||
       memcmp(pwvHdr.FormatSig, "fmt ", 4) ||
       memcmp(pwvHdr.DataSig, "data", 4))
   return 1;
```

Declaring the format and descriptor for a buffer and filling them:

```
DSBUFFERDESC bufDesc;
WAVEFORMATEX wvFormat;

ZeroMemory(&wvFormat, sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
    wvFormat.wFormatTag     = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wvFormat.nChannels      = kickHdr.Channels;
    wvFormat.nSamplesPerSec = kickHdr.SampleRate;
    wvFormat.wBitsPerSample = kickHdr.BitsPerSample;
    wvFormat.nBlockAlign    = wvFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8 * wvFormat.nChannels;

ZeroMemory(&bufDesc, sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC));
    bufDesc.dwSize = sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC);
    bufDesc.dwFlags = DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME | 
                      DSBCAPS_CTRLPAN |
                      DSBCAPS_CTRLFREQUENCY;
    bufDesc.dwBufferBytes = kickHdr.DataSize;
    bufDesc.lpwfxFormat = &wvFormat;
```

Well, the creating of a buffer:

```
device->CreateSoundBuffer(&bufDesc, &kickbuf, NULL); // Any mistakes by this point?
```

Now locking the buffer and loading some data to it.
This data starts after **sizeof(sWaveHeader)** bytes in a WAVE file, am I wrong?

```
LPVOID Ptr1;     // pointer on a pointer on a First block of data 
LPVOID Ptr2;     // pointer on a pointer on a Second block of data
DWORD Size1, Size2;  // their sizes
```

Now calling the Lock() method:

```
kickbuf->Lock((DWORD)LockPos, (DWORD)Size,
                             &Ptr1, &Size1,
                             &Ptr2, &Size2, 0);
```

Loading data (is it ok?):

```
fseek(fkick, sizeof(sWaveHeader), SEEK_SET);
fread(Ptr1, 1, Size1, fkick);
    if(Ptr2 != NULL)
        fread(Ptr2, 1, Size2, fkick);
```

Unlocking the buffer:

```
kickbuf->Unlock(Ptr1, Size1, Ptr2, Size2);
```

Setting the volume:

```
kickbuf->SetVolume(-2500);
```

Then I make a wile(1) looping:
1. ask for a key pressing
2. if it is pressed:

```
kickbuf->SetCurrentPosition(0)
kickbuf->Play(0,0,0);
```

But there's no sound playing, please say, what is not proper in my code or maybe in the whole concept. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize the WAVEFORMATEX, your are forgetting to set the nAvgBytesPerSec member.  Add this line after the initialization of wvFormat.nBlockAlign:

```
wvFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = wvFormat.nSamplesPerSec * wvFormat.nBlockAlign;
```

Also, I suspect this could be a problem:

```
kickbuf->SetVolume(-2500);
```

I suspect that will just attenuate your sample to absolute silence. Try taking that call out so that it plays at full volume.

But more likely, none of you sample code above shows validation of the return values from any of the DirectSound APIs, nor any of the file I/O values.  Have you validated the HRESULTs returned by all the DSound APIs are returning S_OK?  Have you tried printing or using OutputDebugString to print the values you computed for the members of WAVEFORMATEX?
 Have you debugging the fread calls to validate that you are getting valid data into your buffers?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I have, but didn't notice the ArgBytesPerSec, thanks, if it helps, I'll be thsnkful.

Comment: I suspect CreateSoundBuffer was failing as a result of the WAVEFORMATEX not being initialized correctly.

Comment: I added nAvgBytesPerSec but it didn't work, no sound as it was, maybe some other ways of playing sound remain, @selbie?

Comment: @mrexox - Are you saying that every API above you call is returning S_OK, but no sound?  DSound is an older API, but it should work. There's always waveOutWrite, WASAPI, and XAudio.  All exist for different reasons. For your app, DSound should still be appropriate. I'd rather you properly debug your app than give up and switch to something else that will present a new set of problems. If you debug and still can't figure out which method on IDirectSoundBuffer is failing, then post a minimal sample code somewhere and I'll debug later.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to repeat my steps again and ask if I see some trouble

Comment: I tried to fix my code, rewriting it from the begining, but i didn't help. Debugged it but it seemed to be Ok, or maybe I didn't catch something. The Buffer gets initialized and data gets locked and Play method remain but no sound. If it wouldn't bother you, could you have a look on code? Thank you https://bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com/mrexox/dsound-drums/downloads/sound.c?Signature=Vv%2BEvV2QNIdUATGOXFgVUYfQowQ%3D&Expires=1415772773&AWSAccessKeyId=0EMWEFSGA12Z1HF1TZ82

Comment: Sure.  Can you provide your WAV files as well?

Comment: Nevermind, I found your bugs.  You have two bugs.  1) When calling `IDirectSound::SetCooperativeMode`, you need to pass `DSSCL_PRIORITY` instead of `DSSCL_NORMAL`. 2) Also, your program is exiting after calling the Play method on the buffer.  So you aren't hearing anything because you immediately release the device instead of waiting for the buffer to finish playing.  You need to Sleep the length of the buffer before releasing the buffer.

Comment: Omygod!!!! Realy! It worked, I love you, that you helped me :) Thanks a lot! Omygod!!!